# Head First Java p.139 Battleships ArrayList<> Issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a rookie looking to learn Java. I'm going through the 'Head First Java' book and thoroughly enjoying it. I'm come across an issue when learning to use an `ArrayList<>` instead of a regular `array[]`. I'm getting an exception when trying to assign `int[]` to an `ArrayList<>`, please see the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleDotComGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOfGuesses = 0;
    GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();

    DotCom TheDotCom = new DotCom();
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random()*5);
    int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+2};
    TheDotCom.setLocationCells(locations); <---- Here is the problem.
    boolean isAlive = true;

    while(isAlive == true) {
        String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number");
        String result = TheDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
        numOfGuesses++;
        if (result.equals("Kill")) {
            isAlive = false;
            System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses, to" 
            + "destroy the DotCom");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception reads:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setLocationCells(ArrayList<String>) in the type DotCom is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
```

I've tried changing the `int[] locations = {}` into an `ArrayList<String>` after looking up this issue, and finding only one other person had asked about, using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
        String r1 = Integer.toString(randomNum);
        String r2 = Integer.toString(randomNum+1);
        String r3 = Integer.toString(randomNum+2);
        locations.add(r1);
        locations.add(r2);
        locations.add(r3); ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>;
```

This solves the exception and the program will run but entering a guess into the command line does not return a "Hit, Miss or Kill" value, and I can guess any number. In other words, the game of Battleships does not work.

For you reference, the DotCom class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DotCom {

private ArrayList<String> locationCells;
// private int numOfHits;
// don't need that now.

public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc) {
    locationCells = loc;
}

public String checkYourself(String userInput) {
    String result = "Miss";

    int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);
    if (index >= 0) {
        locationCells.remove(index);

        if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
            result = "Kill";
        } else {
            result = "Hit";
        }
    }

    return result;
    } 

 }
```

Any advice you could offer would be great. I'm nervous that at Chapter.5 I really struggle to come up with usable lines of code on my own, but I'm hoping that this is normal for someone who's got almost no experience? I'm also concerned that this problem is not asked by any one else!

Comment: `locations` is an array of type `int` and not an `ArrayList` as required by the method. Those two do not have too much to do with each other. The name `ArrayList` only suggests that internally an array is used to hold the data.

Comment: Also you probably do not want to use Strings for the cells I guess? If they are just numbers anyway, why not use `Integer`?

Comment: Bare with me, but I inserted your suggestion as follows:

    ArrayList<Integer> locations = Arrays.asList(randomNum, randomNum + 1, randomNum +2);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to override existed method `setLocationCells` with new one, that accepts `int[] loc`. Additionally, it is better to hide `locationCells` inside `DotCom` to exclude it's modification outside this class.

```
class DotCom {

    private final List<String> locationCells = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setLocationCells(List<String> loc) {
        locationCells.clear();

        if (loc != null)
            locationCells.addAll(loc);
    }

    public void setLocationCells(int[] loc) {
        locationCells.clear();

        if(loc != null)
            for(int val : loc) 
                locationCells.add(String.valueOf(val));
    }

}
```

In case you cannot modify `DotCom`, then you can convert `int[]` into `ArrayList<String>` on the client side using `Stream`:

```
TheDotCom.setLocationCells((ArrayList<String>)Arrays.stream(locations).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**P.S.**
In your example, you even do not have to convert `int[]` into `ArrayList<String>`, because you can create `ArrayList<String>` instead of `int[]`, especially when you have only `3` vales in this array.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();
    DotCom dotCom = new DotCom();

    // create and add locations using random generator
    int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 5);
    dotCom.setLocationCells(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(rnd), String.valueOf(rnd + 1), String.valueOf(rnd + 2))));

    boolean alive = true;
    int numOfGuesses = 0;

    while (alive) {
        String result = dotCom.checkYourself(helper.getUserInput("enter a number"));
        numOfGuesses++;

        if ("Kill".equals(result)) {
            alive = false;
            System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses, to" + "destroy the DotCom");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that when I do this, and I quote:
"The nested type DotCom cannot hide an enclosing type".

Comment: OK! You solved it! This works really well. For those wondering why my code does not print out the result, it's because I accidentally deleted the "System.out.println(result);" line.Thank you for your help, you little legend you.